# Full,Differential and Transaction log Backup scheduled at same time

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-backups, database-administration

Consider a situation, we've scheduled a job which backups(Full) database at a interval of 2 hrs. Similarly two more jobs are scheduled, one for the differential and another for log backup scheduled at interval 30 mins and 5 mins each . We've started job ,After two hours all the three jobs will be fired(Full,Differential,Log) therefore which will be done first as they all are scheduled to same time.

1) If Full BackUp is performed, then diff(backup) will be of Zero changes?

2) Similarly what will be case of transaction, and how can we know which fired first rather than using LSN (**EASY METHOD** to know).

Comment: From my testing the Full always ran first. I read https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0948f4a7-ff06-4c1e-8518-bb5afd3b28e2/differential-backup-and-transaction-log-at-the-same-time?forum=sqldisasterrecovery that the schedule created first will run first which in my testing was not true. I tested this by creating a schedule for the differential first and then the full. I verified the differential was first in sysjobschedules. When the time came the Full still ran first.

Comment: If Full runs first ,then what will be diff backup?(As it only backs up the changes after Full backup.)

Comment: exactly. Only the changes that occurred since that most recent full but since you have a full I supposed you don't actually need that differential at that point. What you could do is offset the differential so it happens one second earlier. Then it's guaranteed to run first.

Comment: Thanks for your support. i ll look into this :)

Comment: According to my testing, I have seen that log backup runs first,then the differential backup and at last the full backup job is fired (scheduled at same time). Therefore considering this, **Differential** be considering the last full backup as base(Changes will be captured according to last full backup).

Comment: I wonder why we are getting different results. I tried a number of different ways. Maybe ask Microsoft what the expected behavior is.